# How to pass a python string containing @ character character in a MEL.Eval function

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya, mel

Im trying to pass a path containing a @ special character in a FBX export mel command using the mel python package.

```
fullPath = "E:\SomeFolder\Prefix@MyFile.fbx"
mel.eval('FBXExport -f "{}" -s'.format(fullPath))
```

Im getting this error

```
RuntimeError: Error occurred during execution of MEL script
# Line 1.14: Syntax error #
```

I've tried **repr** with Python but it seems to be a MEL sided error.

```
mel.eval('FBXExport -f "{}" -s'.format(repr(fullPath)))
```

Comment: Have you tried using escape character before `@`?

Comment: @Yash since the file name is user input I dont really know how I can use an escape character

Comment: Maya does not allow special characters.